# Use .htaccess to redirect to add .txt extension

Tags: htaccess, redirects, mod-rewrite

I have a `.txt` file on my hosting and would like to redirect to it if somebody enters an specific website within their browser, e.g.

```
example.com/webpage  -->  redirects to  --> example.com/webpage.txt
```

I have tried few rewrite rules, but without success. Is it even doable like this?

Comment: Please show what you have tried and what other directives you have in your `.htaccess` file. This should be a simple redirect, so if it's not working then there may be a conflict with other directives, or maybe there is a minor error with your attempt.

Comment: Not sure if this belgian link will work for you but I use this tool to test my htaccess https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/